# eBay search form

Tags: html, css, forms

I'm working on a website for my work and it's for our eBay webpage. eBay no longer supports active content. So I had to remove our JS and active content but there is one bit of active content I can't remove. My search bar contains a form action which I guess will no longer be supported. I'm on mobile so I'll try to display HTML correctly in my question. Currently, I have:

```
<form name="frm" action="(store link)">
  <input name="_nkw" class="inputbb" type="text" placeholder="search">
</form>
```

How can I link it to the store not using action?

Answer (score 0):

## eBay FAQs

I don't have an eBay store to play with, so can't give a full walkthrough answer, but found the following info in [the eBay FAQs](http://pages.ebay.com/seller-center/faq/stores.html#store-design):

> **Can I use HTML to design my Store home page?**
>   Yes. Store sellers can create a custom header with HTML just below the standard eBay Store header. In addition, Store sellers can build a completely customized Store home page using HTML. To take advantage of these customization opportunities, go to the Manage My Store page and click on "Store Design" in the left column. Sellers can also easily create links to their Store by using HTML Builder, located in the left column in Manage My Store.

You'll see that a couple of the terms used in that quote are linked to *your store* pages, so linking them here is unlikely to work.

Also, according to [this resource](http://pages.ebay.co.uk/help/stores/contextual/custom-listing-header.html):

> **Key elements in a Shop listing header**
>   Your Shop listing header always includes your Shop name, a link to your Shop home page, and your Shop colours. You can also include:
>   * Your Shop logo
>   * A search box that enables buyers to search your Shop
>   * ...

Followed by:

> **Creating or editing your Shop listing header**
>   * To create or edit your Shop listing header:
>   * Go to My eBay and log in if required.
>   * Click Manage My Shop in the left navigation.
>   * Click Listing Template in the left navigation.

And here's [another resource with similar information](https://pages.ebay.co.uk/help/sell/creating-your-store.html).